# How to reduce the number of ticks in x axes in boxplot?

Tags: python-3.x, boxplot

I have a boxplot of the dataframe with large amount of boxes.
I can not figure out how can I reduece number of ticks in th x label.

I use this code to made my figure:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

df2.boxplot(column=['age_gps_data'], by='kilom_100', ax=ax)`
```

I achieve next figure:

[image]

What is the way to show less ticks, for example evey 10th tick. To make my ticks visiable and readeble.
Thank you in adavnce!

Comment: You can set the ticks https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html

Comment: @abhilb i tried  this: `ax.set_xticks(ticks = [635,640,645,650], minor=False)` but it didnt work correctly for me. It just compress all my plot. and in the end set few ticks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(40000).reshape(400,100), columns=np.arange(100))
ax = df.boxplot(return_type='axes')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,100,step=10))
ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(0,11))
plt.show()
```

Comment: it works, but it sets labels from 1 to 10. And i need that it will be from 0 to 100 like in your example. so where is first label 1 should be number 10.

Comment: It has for me the same result with ticks from 1 till 9

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is your requirement. But you can change the tick positions and labels as I shown in the code. You will have to figure out the correct arguments to those two functions